# Add javascript raw file (that is not a module) to build

Tags: webpack, node-modules, es6-modules

I have separated the following file using code splitting to be able to change it in the own build on the fly (without recompiling):

```js
// app/src/env.ts

window.process.env.API_HOST = 'http://localhost:8000'
window.process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development'
```

But my generated JS file looks like this:

```js
// app/build/env.bundle.js

"use strict";
(self["webpackChunkmypackage"] = self["webpackChunkmypackage"] || []).push([[338],{

/***/ 7100:
/***/ (() => {


window.process.env.API_HOST = 'http://localhost:8000';
window.process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';


/***/ })

}]);
//# sourceMappingURL=env.bundle.js.map
```

Is it possible to keep the original raw format for this particular file with some loader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the `CopyPlugin` of webpack. Create your raw javascript file in your project and then make webpack place it in the top level of the build:

```js
    plugins: [
      new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
          // copy "src/env.js" to top level of build ("build/env.js")
          { from: './src/env.js', to: '.' },
        ]
      })
    ],
```

Add the file manually to your html entrypoint of your SPA:

```html
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Your app</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Following line imports the file manually -->
  <script src="/env.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>Enabling JavaScript is required to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```